# uint: Why is -(a*b) different from -a*b

Tags: python, uint

I understand all of these apart from the last one:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(5).astype('uint16')

a
Out[24]: array(5, dtype=uint16)

-a
Out[25]: 65531

a*1.
Out[26]: 5.0

-(a*1.)
Out[27]: -5.0

0-a*1.
Out[28]: -5.0

-a*1.
Out[29]: 65531.0

type(a*1.)
Out[30]: numpy.float64
```

In the last line a uint variable is multiplied with a float resulting in a float, so why is the result of `-a*1.` not -5.0, and how is this different from `-(a*1.)` and `0-a*1.`?

Comment: I guess `(a * 1.)` results in a float, so the order of operations matters. Try `type(a * 1.)`.

Comment: Read: [6.17. Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

Comment: An unsigned `int16` can store numbers from `0` to `65536`. If you get over or under this range the value can overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-a*1.` is `(-a)*1.`, because unary `-` has a [higher precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than `*`. For details, look at the excerpts from the Python grammar in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations).

Answer (score 1):

I think it is due to the order of operations:
`-a*1.` is from left to right, but `0-a*1.` it is a subtraction (even if it is zero) and the `0-` is applied *after* `a*1.` (where the type of the object is changed).

Comment: Didn't realise 'negative' is different from 'subtraction'!